# Wordpress change role from administrator to author by itself (automatically)

Tags: wp-admin, users, login, user-roles, user-access

do anybody know this kind of phenomenon? I do not have any user managing plugins installed in my WP, but after some interaction e.g. editing pages or creating postings (its not matter) WP changes for my logged in user the role from Administrator to Author. It already happens few times. I do also not know where to start with the root cause analysis. I will be happy for any kind of information which helps me to go the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the list of the plugins you have on your website ? You should start with removing all the plugins and see what happens. (By any chance, dont you have Authorizer activated ?).

Comment: I'd stick error_log() trace into any function that sets or changes role, or just everything set or update in the WP_User class, and the add/update/delete_user_meta functions too.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but do not have enough reputation on stackoverflow to add a comment under yours. So my reply then here.

I can list all my plugins but how I should reproduce it, because it happens randomly. And how should I put a error_log() in each function? I do not have the "Autorizer" so this should not be the issue.

I somewhere a general error log of WP to have a look on? I do not now where to start with the analysis. The deactive each plugin not helps, because I not know in which activity this role changing happening.

Comment: Did you write the question? You would have permission to comment if you logged in with that account.

Comment: error_log() e.g. open wp-includes/user.php, find "function update_user_meta" which is line 1196 for me, and then inside the function braces add two lines `error_log("update_user_meta user_id=$user_id meta_key=$meta_key meta_value=".print_r($meta_value,true));` and `error_log(print_r(debug_backtrace(), true));`. Then when it goes wrong look at your server error log for any update_user_meta calls that changed 'role'.

Comment: Yes i am. I was not able to reach my old account. I will test your approach and will give an update. Thanks for the hint.